Restrict number of running Spring instances when running Gradle tests
We're developing a Spring Boot project. We have a lot of integration tests which start up the whole application.
The application has a lot of configurable stuff which means a lot of the test classes use
@TestPropertySource(properties = [..])

to test individual configuration behavior.
If we run these all our tests (the whole test suite), for example with Gradle, the logic behind is pretty clever. Every time a different configuration is detected a new instance of the project will be started.
All running instances are kept which is very handy because if another test uses the same configuration, the instance is still there and can be reused. At the end of the test suite all instances are clothed.
Sadly we're reaching the point where 50+ instances are kept, which is going to be a problem regarding to memory.
Is there a way to configure the maximum number of kept instances?
Versions:

Java 17
Gradle 7.6
Spring Boot 3.2.3


Do all of those tests need a full blown application context? If you follow the recommended practices such as constructor injection (no field injection), you often don't need the full blown application context and can get by with stubs or mocks.

maybe the maxParallelForks option for your gradle Task can help you start fewer parallel instances of your application?
